# Как сохранить и изменять input checked?

Tags: php

Купил панель управления - шаблон.
Пытаюсь кнопку Checked сделать рабочей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно, чтобы при активной Checked, что-то сохранилось в glang, а при не активной Checked, glang должен остаться пустым.

Как реализовать эту функцию, чтобы сама кнопка тоже изменялась от того glang пуст или нет?

Первый раз столкнулся с Checked и понятия не имею как с ней работать :(

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Сам код:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
   <label class="switch switch-primary">
        <input id="glang" type="checkbox"><span></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

значение пусто или задано сохраняю в    `glang    :$("#glang").val(),`

вывожу `<?php echo $config["glang"] ?>`

Мне предложили сделать так `<input id="glang" type="checkbox" <?php if ($on) echo "checked"; ?>>` у меня получилось сохранить данные в базу и все. 
Изменяя значение кнопки и сохраняя его, изменений самой кнопки нет.

Если checked то в базе должно сохраниться, к примеру - **checked**.
Если не checked то в базе **ничего быть не должно** для поля glang.
Потом при загрузке страницы, если в базе в поле glang стоит checked, значит кнопка должна быть активной т.е. checked. При изменении кнопки, в базе данные тоже должны измениться (checked или пусто).

Помогите пожалуйста.

p.s. Вот так у меня реализован выбор кол-ва страниц

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="val_skill">Количество страниц</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                     <select class="form-control" id="count_featured" value="<?php echo $config["count_featured"] ?>">
                     <option value="<?php echo $config["count_featured"] ?>" selected="">Установлено: <?php echo $config["count_featured"] ?></option>
                     <option value="5">5</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="15">15</option>
                     </select>
                </div>
```

Как применить для checked не понимаю :(
База у меня это php файл.

Answer (score 1):

Чекбоксы чаще всего хранятся в базе в виде 1 || 0 (да или нет). Логика Вашего приложения должна быть такая:

Вы выбираете чекбоксы и нажимаете сохранить, далее в файле обработчике получаете данные и заносите в БД в виде 1 если включен 0 если не включен.

В файле с чекбоксами делаем запрос в БД и получаем значения чекбокса и подставляем их в value, заходим в фйл js и пишем что-то вроде этого:

```
      $('ВАШ ЧЕКБОКС').each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == 1)
            {
                $(this).attr('checked',true);
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).attr('checked',false);

            }
        });
```

Для более детального разбирательства выложите файл где это все прописано и получите больше советов...

Comment: В том то и дело, что у меня в файле все так и прописано как в вопросе, больше ничего нет. В input только id="glang", value нет вообще, было бы value, я возможно смог бы разобраться.

Comment: Пойдем другим путем, откройте панель разработчика и при клике на чекбокс посмотрите изменяется его значение или нет...

Comment: Нет, не изменяется. В самом шаблоне есть только <input type="checkbox" checked> и <input type="checkbox"> https://demo.pixelcave.com/proui/page_forms_components.php

Comment: Покажите файл куда отправляется запрос, я думаю это config.php

Comment: Да. в config.php у меня хранится сама база https://i.gyazo.com/59900776b601e32895b390d3c9796ee2.png Этим glang    :$("#glang").val(), я сохраняю данные.

Comment: `<input id="glang" type="checkbox" <?php $glang=". '$config[glang]' ."; if ($glang) echo "checked"; ?>>` может здесь else добавить? Не получается у меня ничего.